# DBCP does not close cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

We are using DBCP2 to create connection pool, jdk 1.7, Oracle 12c, ojdbc6.jar.
Few days back we start getting ORA-01000 error in our application.

I used the following query to find current open cursors in Oracle:

```
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid
and b.name = 'opened cursors current';
```

I kept on hitting the same page multiple times, for executing the same query. following were the observations:
1. When connection pools maxTotal= -1 (unlimited) then many connections were getting opened and in open cursors (value) column the value was 1 or max 2 for some connections.
Eg. sample output of the query was

```
value      sid
1          1
1          2
1          3
```

2. When connection pools maxTotal=10 then only 10 connection were getting opened (10 records returned by the above query) and the open cursor (value) column was increasing.
   Eg. sample output of the query was

   `value      sid
   1          1
   2          2
   3          3
   1          4
   1          5
   3          6`

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate which does closing of all resultset, prepared statements and connections.

My query is:

1. When the connection is returning back to the pool why does open cursor show a value? say 1.
2. When the same connection is used again then the value increases. Does DBCP does not clean the connection before giving it again from the pool?
3. How to clean the connection before its used again, so that open cursors can be closed.

Any help will be great

Comment: Show some code and how you configured your transactions.

Comment: We are using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

Comment: Having that configured doesn't mean you are using it. Hence the request for some code and configuration and please add that to the question not as comments.